# Finding text AND fields with variable content in Word

Tags: ms-word, find, field, wildcard

I need to find and delete every occurrence of the following pattern in a Word 2010 document:

```
RPDIS→ text {INCLUDEPICTURE c:\xxx\xxx.png" \*MERGEFORMAT} text ←RPDIS
```

Where:

1. `RPDIS→` and `←RPDIS` are start and end delimiters
2. Between the start and end delimiters there can be just text or text and fields with variable content

The `*` wildcard in the Word Find and Replace dialog box will find the pattern if it contains text only but it will ignore patterns where text is combined with fields. And `^19` will find the field but not the rest of the pattern until the end delimiter.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA solution. It wildcard searches for `RPDIS→*←RPDIS`. If the found text contains ^19 (assuming field codes visible; if objects are visible instead of field codes, then the appropriate test is text contains ^01), the found text is deleted. Note that this **DOES NOT** care about the type of embedded field --- it will delete **ANY AND ALL** embedded fields that occur between `RPDIS→` and `←RPDIS`, so use at your own risk. Also, the code has `ChrW(8594)` and `ChrW(8592)` to match right-arrow and left-arrow respectively. You may need to change that if your arrows are encoded differently.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
    Dim r As Word.Range
    Dim s As String
    ' Const c As Integer = 19  ' Works when field codes are visible
    Const c As Integer = 1  ' Works when objects are visible

    Set wdDoc = ActiveDocument
    Set r = wdDoc.Content

    With r.Find
        .Text = "RPDIS" & ChrW(8594) & "*" & ChrW(8592) & "RPDIS"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        While .Execute
            s = r.Text
            If InStr(1, s, chr(c), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Delete: " & s
                ' r.Delete   ' This line commented out for testing; remove comments to actively delete
            Else
                Debug.Print "Keep: " & s
            End If
       Wend
    End With
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I edited your question to reflect your comments then made corresponding changes in the answer.

Comment: I have tried with a Word document containing only the text below, and it does not seem to work. What did I do wrong?

TEXT:
I want to keep this text RPDIS→  to be deleted { INCLUDEPICTURE "P%20E%20R%20S%20O%20N%20N%20E%20L/Images/emo_happy.gif" \x \y \* MERGEFOMAT }  to be deleted ←RPDIS, and nothing more.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by "... it does not seem to work ...". Can you give a specific example of the text you start with **and** the text you want remaining after find/replace?

Comment: Is there any way to upload a Word document containing the exact text that I want to replace, please?
Thank you again.

Comment: I have uploaded an extract of my document at the following location : ecolinguae.com/Extract.doc. Can you have a look, please? This is supposed to generate 2 documents from the same single source.

Comment: Can you help again, please?

Comment: Please,  xidgel, can you have a look? Thank you.

Comment: xidgel, please, can you help?